# There is no sharing tab in connection properties

Tags: networking, internet, windows-8.1

I'm trying to make Android 4.4.2 device [Micromax Unite 2 - A106](http://www.micromaxinfo.com/mobiles/smartphones/canvas/Unite-2-A106) to share PC's internet connection.

I've a PC at home which has highspeed broadband internet connection. I don't have wireless router or access point. I just want to use PC's internet connection on my phone.

In my phone when I connect my phone, in `Settings > Wireless & networks > USB Internet (sharing Windows PC internet via USB cable)` checkbox, which I checked then it asked me to choose my Windows version (which is Windows 8.1 but since it didn't show that option) I chose Windows 8.  It gives me further instructions as showing in the following picture:

[image]

Here is the problem, there is no **sharing tab** (see the following screen shot)
[image]

How to get a sharing tab in connection properties?

Comment: This question is part of my question on android.stackexchange: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable/74729#74729

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/159304-internet-connection-sharing.html#post1366478) or [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/sharing-tab-missing-in-my-lan-settings/7099a998-5d5a-4e3d-8c3a-9d3fec3875e2) for the sharing tab problem - then restart explorer.exe / computer and see if you see anything

Comment: @claws let me know if it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can't enable sharing with only one network connection. It only works if you have 2 connections (Ethernet & Ethernet, Ethernet & WiFi or WiFi & WiFi).

Answer (score 1):

turn off the sharing option from Local area network ..
now, try opening the properties of wireless network, sharing tab will be available..

sharing option cannot be available for two networks at the same instance..

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one internet connection (like an Ethernet and Wifi) and one does not have the sharing tab check the other connection.  You may find it there I did and it fixed my prob.  I believe if you are looking for it and you don't yet have another connection there is no point for the tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bridge a wired network to ad-hoc wifi, straight from the Windows 7 GUI.  Instead of trying to unhide the Sharing tab, do this.

Install a program that's designed to bridge like this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/networkbridgingutility/.

Click start, type `cmd.exe`, right-click "run as administrator," and `cd` to whichever folder you copied `bridgeutil.exe` to.

`bridgeutil.exe /install` installs the special driver for the Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter.

`bridgeutil.exe` lists numbers for the networks it found (and then a long usage message).  If the numbers for the wired network and the miniport adapter happen to be 5 and 6,

`bridgeutil.exe /attach 5 /attach 6`.

Back in the GUI, you can confirm that "control panel > network and sharing center > change adapter settings" shows both those networks as "enabled, bridged."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the sharing tab only shows up when you have two network connections. I had a removable Ethernet over USB and I needed to disable sharing to install Cisco AnyConnect. To accomplish this without my Ethernet over USB device I just uninstalled the WiFi device driver and rebooted. This restored the WiFi device to defaults with network sharing disabled.